# two header or source files refering to each other

Tags: c++

I am trying to make chess. In class figure I put a pointer to object square, that points at its "location" and vice versa: in square a pointer to figure. The problem is that definitions of these classes are in separate files. When I wrote `#include "square.cpp"` in figure.cpp and vice versa, compiler show many errors in the lines with #include, like:

from [path to figure]
 from [path to square]

Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: Google `forward declaration`. Never ever have .h files that include each other.

Comment: Separate your code into .h and .cpp files, and include only .h files.

Comment: Off-Topic: I'm curious about your design. Why do Figure and Square know each other?

Comment: @MABVT Inside Figure I have got virtual methods that determine if it can move. They need to know its coordinates of its actual and potential  square, and if it is free or occupied by enemy. Square needs to see by whom is it possessed to allow its button interact whit it.

Comment: You could - in further steps - refactor that logic out into a "ChessRuleService". That service knows all rules, the Figures, Squares and its relations. You could then do something like a "service.queryMovementAllowed(fig : Figure, action : Movement) : bool;".
The button state can be updated by doing a "service.queryPermittedActions(sq : Square, fig : Figure) : List<Action>;".

The Figure and Square-class use an "IChessRuleService"-interface (IChessRuleService.h), which eliminates the circular dependencies between Figure, Square and the ChessRuleService-imp.

This is how i would do it. :D

Comment: Keep me updated about your project! I'm interested in your progress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, notice that you could avoid any application `#include` (so only include system headers or headers for external libraries) and just copy & paste source code into several files. That would be inconvenient. Read more about the [C preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor). Notice that it is mostly doing *textual* processing (e.g. does not know much about C++ syntax or [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree)s).

Then, *conventionally*, header files contain mostly *declarations* (of types, `struct`, `class`, functions, variables, ...) and *definitions* of `static inline` functions (or `inline` member functions of your `class`-es).

So you'll better not `#include "square.cpp"` in your `figure.cpp` source file, but just have a single `myheader.h` file with a `#include "myheader.h"` both in your `square.cpp` and your `figure.cpp` source files (i.e. [translation units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29)).

Read more books [about C++ programming](http://stroustrup.com/programming.html) and study the source code of some C++ [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), e.g. [hun7err's Chess](https://github.com/hun7err/Chess) and [ChessPlusPlus](https://github.com/cpluspluscom/ChessPlusPlus) (I am not expert in chess programming, and found both of them thru quick google searches)

Answer (score 0):

try adding include guards in the header:

```
#ifndef YOURHEADER_H_ //at the start of the file
#define YOURHEADER_H_
// the header contents
#endif //this has to be at the end of the file
```

Comment: This won't help with two classes that refer to each other.